# Mínimo en un periodo utilizando Diccionarios C#

Tags: c#, linq

Buenos días nuevamente SOes,

Siguiendo un poco sobre mi pregunta anterior sobre diccionarios, estoy luchando nuevamente con los GroupBy.

El planteo es el siguiente:

- Saber el Minimo Gasto del periodo (2 dias) de cada Mercado.

Poseo los siguientes archivos de textos:

**CLIENTES**

`ID_CLIENTE  CLIENTE MERCADO
1198        CTA           G
1285        FGF           B
1112        EJESA         B
1131        ESPERANZA     F
1150        NORP          B
1141        LUQUE         B
1151        TUCU          F
1235        BERNV         G`

**GASTO**

```
FECHA           ID_CLIENTE  GASTO
01/08/2017      1198        25647   
01/08/2017      1285        4885
01/08/2017      1112        71987
01/08/2017      1131        1000
01/08/2017      1150        5
01/08/2017      1141        98
01/08/2017      1151        84
01/08/2017      1235        5899
02/08/2017      1198        257 
02/08/2017      1285        4885
02/08/2017      1112        1987
02/08/2017      1131        1489
02/08/2017      1150        5489
02/08/2017      1141        8
02/08/2017      1151        841
02/08/2017      1235        589
```

**CLASES:**

```
    public class Cliente
    {
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Mercado { get; set; }
    }


public class Consumo
    {
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public int Gasto { get; set; }
    }
```

**IMPORTACIÓN DE ARCHIVOS:**

```
public class Importar
    {
        string path;
        string NombreArchivo;
        protected string[] lineas;
        public Importar(string path, string nombreArchivo)
        {
            // Verifica existencia del archivo
            var na = path + nombreArchivo;
            if (!File.Exists(na))
                throw new Exception(string.Format("No existe al archivo {0}", na));

            lineas = File.ReadAllLines(na);
        }
    }
        // Importa datos del archivo cliente.txt a una lista.
        public class ImportarCliente : Importar
        {
            public ImportarCliente(string path, string nombreArchivo) :
                  base(path, nombreArchivo)
            { }

            public List<Cliente> ImportarArchivo()
            {
                List<Cliente> result = new List<Cliente>();
                for (int i = 1; i < lineas.Length; i++)
                {
                    var items = lineas[i].Split(new char[] { '\t' });
                    Cliente c = new Cliente()
                    {
                        IdCliente = Convert.ToInt32(items[0]),
                        Nemonico = items[1],
                        Mercado = items[2]
                    };
                    result.Add(c);
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        // Importa datos del archivo consumo.txt a una lista.
        public class ImportarConsumo : Importar
        {
            public ImportarConsumo(string path, string nombreArchivo) :
                base(path, nombreArchivo)
            { }

            public List<Consumo> ImportarArchivo()
            {
                List<Consumo> result = new List<Consumo>();
                for (int i = 1; i < lineas.Length; i++)
                {
                    var items = lineas[i].Split(new char[] { '\t' });
                    Consumo c = new Consumo()
                    {
                        DiaOperativo = Convert.ToDateTime(items[0]), /*antes ParseExact, ahora DateTime.*/
                        IdCliente = Convert.ToInt32(items[1]),
                        Facturado = Convert.ToInt32(items[2])
                    };
                    result.Add(c);
                }
                return result;
            }

        }
```

**CARGADO DE LISTAS:**

```
  // Cargado de listas clientes
        dClientes = Clientes.ToDictionary(c => c.IdCliente, v => v);


        // Consumos con IdCliente
        dConsumos = Consumos.Where(c => dClientes.Keys.Contains(c.IdCliente)).
        GroupBy(c => c.IdCliente).
        ToDictionary(c => c.Key, v => v.ToList<Consumo>());
```

Y definí las siguientes variables para resolver el problema:

```
List<Cliente> Clientes;
    List<Consumo> Consumos;

    Dictionary<int, Cliente> dClientes;
    Dictionary<int, List<Consumo>> dConsumos;

    public Reporte(List<Cliente> Clientes, List<Consumo> Consumos)
    {
        this.Clientes = Clientes;
        this.Consumos = Consumos;
    }
```

Ahora volviendo al problema en cuestión, realicé la siguiente consulta:

```
var agruparMercado = Clientes.Where(c => dConsumos.Keys.Contains(c.IdCliente))
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Mercado)
                    .Select(z => new
                    {
                        Mercado = z.Key,
                        Minimo = Consumos.Where(x => z.Select(y => y.IdCliente).Contains(x.IdCliente)).Min(x => x.Gasto)

                    });
```

**RESULTADO OBTENIDO:**

```
MERCADO    MINIMO GASTO
G             257
B             5
F             84
```

**RESULTADO DESEADO:**

```
MERCADO    MINIMO GASTO
    G             6488
    B             106
    F             925
```

Es decir, recibo el mínimo consumo por cliente y lo que necesito obtener es el Mínimo por el período de los clientes.
MERCADO: B | CLIENTE: 114 | DIA1: 98 + DIA2: 8 = 106.

Un saludo, estoy a disposición de cualquier duda sobre la pregunta planteada.

Answer (score 4):

Otra solucion, mas ordenadita para que se entienda que hace cada paso:

Primero y principal, para entregar un ejemplo, podrias hacer algo asi:

```
List<Cliente> ListaCliente = new List<Cliente>
            {
                new Cliente { IdCliente = 1198, Nombre = "CTA", Mercado = "G" },
                new Cliente { IdCliente = 1285, Nombre = "FGF", Mercado = "B" },
                new Cliente { IdCliente = 1112, Nombre = "EJESA", Mercado = "B" },
                new Cliente { IdCliente = 1131, Nombre = "ESPERANZA", Mercado = "F" },
                new Cliente { IdCliente = 1150, Nombre = "NORP", Mercado = "B" },
                new Cliente { IdCliente = 1141, Nombre = "LUQUE", Mercado = "B" },
                new Cliente { IdCliente = 1151, Nombre = "TUCU", Mercado = "F" },
                new Cliente { IdCliente = 1235, Nombre = "BERNV", Mercado = "G" }
            };
```

De esa forma facilitas las pruebas a todo el mundo ;)

segundo, hagamos lo que queres hacer por pasos.

Paso 1: agrupar por cliente:

```
var resul3 = ListaConsumo.GroupBy(
                x => x.IdCliente,
                x => x.Gasto,
                (BaseId, sumas) =>
                new
                {
                    key = BaseId,
                    Suma = sumas.Sum()
                }
                );
```

Paso 2: Joinear con los mercados

```
var resul4 = resul3.Join(ListaCliente,
            x => x.key,
            y => y.IdCliente,
            (x, y) =>
            new
            {
                id = x.key,
                gastos = x.Suma,
                mercado = y.Mercado
            }
            );
```

Paso 3: obtener el minimo por mercado

```
        var resul5 = resul4.GroupBy(
            x => x.mercado,
            y => y.gastos,
            (BaseId, Minimos) =>
            new
            {
                key = BaseId,
                Minimo = Minimos.Min()
            }
            );
```

o todo junto

```
var resul6 = ListaConsumo.GroupBy(
            x => x.IdCliente,
            x => x.Gasto,
            (BaseId, sumas) =>
            new
            {
                key = BaseId,
                Suma = sumas.Sum()
            }
            ).Join(ListaCliente,
            x => x.key,
            y => y.IdCliente,
            (x, y) =>
            new
            {
                id = x.key,
                gastos = x.Suma,
                mercado = y.Mercado
            }).GroupBy(
            x => x.mercado,
            y => y.gastos,
            (BaseId, Minimos) =>
            new
            {
                key = BaseId,
                Minimo = Minimos.Min()
            }
            );
```

Y para verlo por consola, basta hacer:

```
foreach (var v in resul6)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Mercado: {v.key}, Minimo: {v.Minimo}");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Antes de dar la respuesta, aclarar que esta es solo una de las multiples formas de conseguir el resultado esperado. Unas mas fáciles, otras mas complicadas.

En este caso, primero agrupo los clientes por mercado, y posteriormente sumo los importes de gasto de cada cliente, creando una nueva clase anónima.

Una vez hecho eso, para mostrarlo simplemente recorremos la colección resultante, y para cada mercado mostramos el Mercado del primer elemento (son todos iguales) y el mínimo de los gastos de los clientes de ese mercado.

```
var MinimoPorMercado = dClientes.GroupBy(x => x.Value.Mercado).Select(y => new
{
    minimo = Consumos.GroupBy(x => x.IdCliente)
                        .Select(z => new { IdCliente = z.Key,
                                        Mercado = y.First().Value.Mercado,
                                        Gasto = z.Sum(yy => yy.Gasto) })
                        .Where(x => y.Select(z => z.Value.IdCliente).Contains(x.IdCliente))
});

foreach (var grupo in MinimoPorMercado)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", grupo.minimo.First().Mercado, grupo.minimo.Min(x => x.Gasto));
}
```

O, si necesitas tener los datos en un enumerable, haces un select de ambos campos (mercado y minimo):

```
var MinimoPorMercado = dClientes.GroupBy(x => x.Value.Mercado).Select(y => new
{
    minimo = Consumos.GroupBy(x => x.IdCliente)
                        .Select(z => new { IdCliente = z.Key,
                                        Mercado = y.First().Value.Mercado,
                                        Gasto = z.Sum(yy => yy.Gasto) })
                        .Where(x => y.Select(z => z.Value.IdCliente).Contains(x.IdCliente))

})
.Select(x=> new { mercado = x.minimo.First().Mercado, minimo = x.minimo.Min(y => y.Gasto) 
                });

foreach (var grupo in MinimoPorMercado)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", grupo.mercado, grupo.minimo);
}
```